# I am trying to Insert a Node in Sorted Manner in a List using Insertion Sort

Tags: c#, linked-list, insertion-sort, bucket-sort

I am trying to implement Bucket Sort Algorithm in C# on Linked List , but I am getting In correct results. This function should take List and Node in argument and than insert that node at correct ascending order.
I have a list [4, 7, 12, 15]  and I want new Node with data 20 to be Inserted in Ascending order such as this list becomes [4,7,12,15,20].But in result I am getting this list[4,7,12,20,15] Please Help me, What's wrong in it. I guess there is some problem inside while loop. All other functions called by this function are totally working perfect

```
    static public void InsertionSort(LinkedList list, Node s)
            {
                int data = s.getData();
                if (list.start.getNext() == null)
                    list.InsertAtEnd(data);
                else
                {
                    int key = 0; 
                    Node temp = list.start;
                    while (temp.getNext() != null)
                    {
                        temp = temp.getNext();
                        if (data >= temp.getData())
                            key++;

                    }
                    list.InsertAt(key, data);
                }
            }
```

Derived Function (Main Function):

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
            int[] array = { 4, 7, 12, 15 };
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                list.InsertAtEnd(array[i]);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Before Insertion");
            list.Display();
            Node n = new Node(20);
            InsertionSort(list, n);
            System.Console.WriteLine("After Insertion");
            list.Display();
```

Output:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdmso.png): [Output of The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdmso.png)

Comment: Please... instead of linking to an image of your code (which really doesn't help us help you) just copy and paste your code into your question.

Comment: much better! Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I have added the code, Please review it

Comment: are you getting an error or exception? can you add some logging here.

Comment: Next: When you say: `there is some problem In Insertion Sort Function`, please tell us what the problem is. `some problem` does not help us. If there is an error message, show us the error. Or if the code runs with no error, then show us the result, and what you want the result to be.

Comment: No exception is thrown. I am getting in correct result

Comment: there's no need to call s.getData() so many time sin a loop, call it once before.

Comment: If you are getting an incorrect result, then (again) please show us a sample of the result you are getting, and a sample of the result you want.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated again, Please review it

Comment: `This function is not sorting the List Perfectly.` -- Ok, this is the problem? Can you show us the definition of `LinkedList`?

Comment: Show us a list before and after sorting, and what the list should be after sorting.

Comment: I have updated my question, Please review it.

Comment: I have added Complete Code and Output. Now Please Review it and please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Your InsertionSort doesn't sort: it just tries to insert one new node in the right place, based on the count of elements that it is bigger than. (And still seems to be off by one?) Which would only work if the list was in order already, I think, but yours isn't because you've assembled it largest first, because you're adding new elements in increasing order with 'InsertAtBegin' not 'InsertAtEnd'

Comment: You also haven't shown us the LinkedList class, which is not the standard C# LinkedList I don't think, or Node, but unless there are errors in where LinkedList inserts new items it may just be the InsertionSort function that's wrong.

Comment: You could also probably simplify the while loop: assuming the original list is in order, you can stop when you find the first element that's larger than the new one and then stop there and insert the new element before it. You don't need to loop through the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

The setup in the beginning is wrong.

```
int[] array = { 4, 7, 12, 15 };
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    list.InsertAtBegin(array[i]);
```

Because you go over the initial array and add all the items at the beginning, the resulting list is sorted in the wrong order.

To start with the correct sorting, either add at the end:

```
int[] array = { 4, 7, 12, 15 };
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    list.InsertAtEnd(array[i]);
```

or go over the initial array in the other direction:

```
int[] array = { 4, 7, 12, 15 };
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list.InsertAtBegin(array[i]);
```

---

Also, your insertion algorithm isn't optimal.

With a linked list, to get to a certain element in the list is expensive because you always have to travel from the start to the correct position.

Your code first tries to find the correct place to insert the new element and then calls another method `InsertAt` which will have to restart traveling the list from the beginning to find the same position again.

Instead, change your code so that you directly insert the new node as soon as you have found an element with a higher value.

Comment: I have tried both InsertAtEnd and InsertATBegining, but still I am getting error

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all of you who tried to help me. I have correct my code. Now It's producing 100% accurate result.

```
static public void InsertionSort(LinkedList list, int data)
        {
            Node n = new Node(data);
            Node temp = list.start;
            Node sNode = null;
            while(temp.getNext() !=null)
            {
                if (data >= temp.getNext().getData())
                    sNode = temp.getNext();
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            if (sNode == null)
                list.InsertAtBegin(data);
            else
                list.InsertAfter(sNode,n);
        }
```

Comment: You always traverse the full list and compare the value to insert with every value in the list. You could stop the while loop once you have found a value that's smaller than the one you want to insert. Also, I suspect that list.start could be null for an empty list? Then you could get NullReferenceExceptions and you would skip the the first item while searching for the right spot to insert.

Comment: At first glance I suspect it will go wrong if you have a LinkedList containing only one number and you try to insert a larger number.